# Are there any plan for elysium 2?

Tags: elysium

Does anyone know if there's any chance that they'll be making a sequel to the film 'Elysium'?

Answer (score 2):

This question will likely be closed as it is really all just speculation that can be changed at any time.

However, Neil Blomkamp is unlikely to return to the Elysium world.

First, [he's got too many ideas to ever really get around to sequels.](http://insidemovies.ew.com/2013/07/27/elysium-district-9-sequel/) (Yes, this quote is more about District 9, but the point is the same.)

> Plus, he’s frankly not in the head space for sequels and franchises just yet. “I’m not actively trying to avoid them,” he tells EW exclusively. “The problem is that I have so many ideas for films that I feel like I’m not going to have enough time to do them all before I die. If I don’t get a chance to at least try making some of those first, I’ll feel like I’ve let myself down.”
>
> Still, there’s hope. If Blomkamp does decide to sequel-ize any of his films, District 9 is at the top of his list. “The world of District 9 has so many hilarious, bizarre, interesting, thematically linked things, and there are multiple stories to tell in that world that are all legitimate.” To do it, he’s just going to have to run out of other ideas, first. “The equation becomes: am I not excited enough about other ideas that I’m willing to return to District 9. And at the moment, I have other things that I’m really into.”

He's also just [not really interested in them in general](http://screencrave.com/2013-08-07/interview-elysium-director-neill-blomkamp-sequels-sharlto-copley-ratings/).

> One of my favorite parts of filmmaking is just conceptualizing ideas. That’s my favorite part. Executing them is very different to conceptualizing them. Because I like conceptualization so much I tend to come up with a lot of ideas. I get attached to a lot of them and so because of that— if you imagine that’s the situation — it creates a different mindset. It’s like I want to see this get executed. I want to see that executed. As opposed to that I want to return back to this world from this film. So it’s really just a mindset like that… I have a few other ideas for films that I want to make currently that I want to see get made that may influence that.

And he has received very little pressure to do a sequel to Elysium.

> It came up once or twice with Elysium. Could we make a sequel out of it? It was extremely minor though. It was as fleeting as the discussion of could the film be 3D. It was the same thing. Very minor.

But that doesn't mean that the studios can't do it without him.

As for other upcoming films "like Elysium", that's just incredibly broad...

Comment: I've edited to make it more specific and within the rules of the site.

Comment: Nice answer.  I'd have thought a sequel was unlikely simply because the 3 most interesting characters (Max Da Costa, Defense Secretary Delacourt & Agent C. M. Kruger) were ..obviously not going to appear in it.